# Python Socket errno 10054 only when client.py runs

Tags: python, sockets, client

There are some other posts about this issue but none did help me with mine.
I'm trying to build a total simple server - client relationship in python

server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1",8889))
s.listen(1)   
try:

    while True:
        client, add = s.accept()
        data = client.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            print 'No data'
        print data

finally:
    s.close()
```

client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",8889))


try:
    while True:
        message = 'Foo'
        s.send(message)
        ans = s.recv(1024)
        print ans
finally:
    s.close()
```

I start by running the server first, but when I try to run the client I'm getting this `Errno 10054 --> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`
While request the browser with the ip and the related port, I receive some data.
I'm quiet new to networking, so please explain what might be obvious wrong in my code.

EDIT* Main issue is, that the client is somehow wrong, because it returns also an empty string on recv

Thank you in advance

Comment: errorTab[10054] = "The connection has been reset." could you post the whole error?

Comment: sure, I updated it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Main issue is, that the client is somehow wrong, because it returns also an empty string on recv
```

The client isn't receiving anything from the server because the server is not sending anything.

On the server side, after `print data`, adding `client.send(data)` will send the string back to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the commenct

now receiving :

WSAECONNABORTED 10053
Software caused connection abort.
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a data transmission time-out or protocol error

I think I will check at home without any restricting firewall, just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing:

The server accepts one socket and then does

```
    client, add = s.accept()
    data = client.recv(1024)
    ...
    client, add = s.accept()
```

The client does this in the mean time:

```
s.send(message)
ans = s.recv(1024) # blocks until timeout
```

If now an other client connects to the server then `client` is replaced, the socket garbage collected and closed. `s.recv(1024)` will then tell that the connection is reset.

Have a look at `import select` or twisted (google around) to handle multiple connections at once.

Comment: but why do I need I need to accept multiple clients when I only request the server with one client script? I got this from a basic example and guessed that should work as expected?

Comment: We do not have the same expectations. So I can not answer what you want to do. Because the client held open the connection and was expecting to receive endlessly and the server accepted mutiple clients, I expected this behaviour to be expected.

Comment: No sorry if my answer is unclear, I just want to build a server and send the response to the client. I'm really new to networking so sorry if it might be unclear

Comment: first part of the answer: Problems will be there because the server closes the connection to the client once there is a new connection to the server.

Comment: I tried this example at home and it works out of the box, it really seems to be that I was behind a blocked port, sorry for any confusion